# windows 10 freeze even if I'm away from keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, event-viewer

I have some problems with my system, sometimes it just freeze.

I was looking into Event Viewer, but I found nothing suspicious (in my opinion) so here is a screenshot of **Windows Logs\System**
[image]

The DistributedCOM has the following message:

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
 and APPID 
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
 to the user My-PC\MyUser SID (S-1-5-21-3773257287-1319484322-915471555-1002) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

Comment: what is "afk"? this freeze is logged as kernel power event with ID41, so check this help page: support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: _"Away from keyboard"_

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the latest drivers from nVidia.com and now it seems to be working ok

I'm glad that it was only a driver problem.

Also there was a driver for nVidia in the updates if I remember well